# How to propagate headers received in Spring WebFlux server with Kotlin coroutine to downstream gRPC server through ClientInterceptor?

Tags: spring, grpc, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, grpc-java

I have a server developed using Spring WebFlux and coroutine in Kotlin.

What I want to do is to concatenate specific request headers into a string and propagate it to downstream gRPC server in a form of a metadata.

For example, let's assume I want to concatenate following 3 headers.

```
header-a: 1
header-b: 2
header-c: 3
```

into following gRPC metadata.

```
headers: header-a=1; header-b=2; header-c=3
```

As far as I know, the best way to handle these cross-cutting concerns in gRPC while requesting is to use ClientInterceptor.

Similarly, the best place to apply common logic for headers in Spring WebFlux would be WebFilter.

What I'm curious about is how I could pass the string made with headers in WebFilter to gRPC ClientInterceptor in order to propagate specific headers to gRPC server without explicit metadata setting for every gRPC call.

Comment: There is a [commit in 6.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/b0aa004d9db74b42d7d17883ed490388261ed96e) that allows you to set the coroutine context in a `CoWebFilter`. There does not seem to be an out-of-the-box solution for using coroutine context in a `ClientInterceptor` though. See [grpc-kotlin#354](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/issues/354)

Comment: @GeorgeLeung Thank you so much for your information! I'll check it out!

Comment: @GeorgeLeung Hey, I've checked the code in the grpc-kotlin repo's issue you've shared, but is it ok to use runBlocking in 'start' method of 'SomeClientCall' class in the code there? I don't want to block the thread every time gRPC call occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This `CoWebFilter` does the concatenation and put the value in a grpc `Context`.

```
@Component
class HeaderCombiner : CoWebFilter() {
    override suspend fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: CoWebFilterChain) {
        val headers = exchange.request.headers
        val value = headerNames.joinToString(separator = "; ") { headerName ->
            "$headerName=${headers.getFirst(headerName)}"
        }

        withContext( // requires spring-web-6.1.0
            GrpcContextElement(
                Context.current().withValue(combinedHeaderContextKey, value)
            )
        ) {
            chain.filter(exchange)
        }
    }
}
```

This `ClientInterceptor` reads the value from the `Context` and put it into the `headers`.  You have to manually add it to the `Channel` by calling `.intercept(CombinedHeaderClientInterceptor)`.

```
object CombinedHeaderClientInterceptor : ClientInterceptor {
    override fun <ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
        method: MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT>,
        callOptions: CallOptions,
        next: Channel,
    ): ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> {
        /**
         * The value is in a [ThreadLocal] [Context]
         * Coroutine callers can see it because of [GrpcContextElement.updateThreadContext]
         */
        val value: String? = combinedHeaderContextKey.get()
        val newCall = next.newCall(method, callOptions)

        return if (value == null) newCall
        else object : SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(newCall) {
            override fun start(responseListener: Listener<RespT>, headers: Metadata) {
                headers.put(combinedHeaderMetadataKey, value)
                super.start(responseListener, headers)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works with coroutines because

1. Since 6.1.0 (Spring Boot 3.2.0), `CoWebFilter` can set the `coroutineContext` of the handler function.
2. `GrpcContextElement` automatically mounts and unmounts the `ThreadLocal` `Context`.

I've tested the above in this repo:
https://github.com/phiSgr/spring-grpc-context-demo/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/com/example/context/HeaderCombiner.kt

Comment: You mentioned 'requires spring-web-6.1.0' in a code snippet as a comment, is it still needed even if I just copy-and-paste CoWebFilter code from latest Spring Github repo(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7f615fd8af27ba6e0a24a42d26bf7373b6c217f8/spring-web/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/web/server/CoWebFilter.kt#L34)?

Comment: `CoWebFilter` writes to the `attributes`, `InvocableHandlerMethod` reads from it; so only replacing the former won't work. Even if it works, still inadvisable.